# How will I know for which utterances test case failed in botium?

Tags: automation, chatbot

If 2 out of 5 utterances are failed using botium, in the report it shows testname-L1, test-name-L2 failed. How will I know for which query it got failed. I have to go to utterances file to check value of L1. Also if I am picking up random utterances, then I am not able to figure out, for which message it got failed. Is there any way to find it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what Botium component you are using.

### Botium Box

In Botium Box, you can browse through the test results (in Test Session / Test Cases) and expand a failing test case to show the full conversation transcript, including the utterance failing the test case.

[image]

### Botium Bindings and Botium CLI

The latest Botium Bindings and Botium CLI builds show the failure details in the test suite result, including the last utterance sent to the chatbot and failing the test case.

[image]